# Return usernames mentioned in post as profile links to those users inside the post

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

Hey guys I'm trying to get my code to check for a user mentioned in a post with @username that is in the database and return that users profile link as the @username. I am currently able to get the users in the backend with the tagged_users variable in my views. It store the users mentioned but how do I access that in the template so that it gives me the link to those users profiles? so far my code is this in the template

```
{% if post.post|slice:":1" == '@' %}
   <a href="{% url 'profile_with_pk' pk=user.username %}">
     {{ post.post }}
   </a>
   {% else %}
   {{ post.post }}
   {% endif %}
```

this returns the entire post as a link but does not return the actual user mentioned in the post instead it makes a link to the current user logged in

This is my code that brings back the users mentioned in the tagged_users list correctly I want to access this in the template as a link to those users profiles in the post.

```
def post(self, request, pk=None):
        if pk:
            user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        else:
            user = request.user
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        users = User.objects.all()
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            tagUsers = re.findall(r"@+(\w+)", post.post)
            tagged_users = list()
            for username in tagUsers: 
                    user = User.objects.get(username=username) 
                    tagged_users.append(user)
                    print(tagged_users)
            text = form.cleaned_data['post']
            form = HomeForm()
            tag = tagged_users
            return redirect('home')


        context = {'form': form, 'text': text, 'users':users, 'user': user, 'tag':tag, 'tagUsers':tagUsers  }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems. Let's start from this one:

```
 <a href="{% url 'profile_with_pk' pk=user.username %}">
     {{ post.post }}
 </a>
```

The whole post is wrapped in the link. I think you want to make a link to the post author, right? Then (with only guessing your model schema that you didn't posted), you need something like this:

```
# iteration through posts somewhere here
<a href="{% url 'profile_with_pk' pk=user.username %}">user.username</a>
{{ post.post }}
```

Next, is that if you have tagged users, you need to somehow put them into the template in your posts. Depending on how you wish to put a link to mentionned users this may be something like:

```
 # iteration through posts somewhere here
<a href="{% url 'profile_with_pk' pk=user.username %}">user.username</a>
{{ post.post }}
Mentions: {% for tagged_user in tagUsers %} {{ tagged_user.username }} {% endfor %}
```

Or maybe you want to insert links directly inside post text? Then you need to construct a post structure before passing it to template (example snipped; will rather need improvements):

```
from django.utils.html import mark_safe

def post(self, request, pk=None):
    ...
    post_text = post.post
    tagUsers = re.findall(r"@+(\w+)", post.post)
    tagged_users = list()
    for username in tagUsers: 
        user = User.objects.get(username=username) 
        for match in re.finditer(username, post_text):
            start = match.start()
            end = match.end()
            profile_link = reverse('profile_with_pk', kwargs={'pk': user.id})
            post_text[start:end] = mark_safe(f'<a href="{profile_link}">username</a>')
    ...
    # return post_text to template context and use in the same way as used post
```

Comment: you have been so much help is there anyway I can buy you a coffee or something? thank you so much

Comment: no really your an angel I'm going to try a few of these out and see if I can get the desired outcome thank you